# Backbone - Using fetched data inside the view

Tags: backbone.js, backbone-views, backbone.js-collections

I have fatched the data to Collection variable, but I am not sure what should I do next. How to use this data and to fill the template with it? Here is my code from the render function inside the View.

```
    Collection.url = "../data";
    Collection.fetch();                         
    var compiled = _.template(self.data);                               
    self.$el.prepend(compiled(/*MY JSON SHOULD GO HERE*/));
```

I am a newbie to backbone, so every help is appreaciated.

Here is a Collection definition:

```
var MainCollection = Backbone.Collection.extend({ 
        model: MainModel,
        //localStorage: new Backbone.LocalStorage("kitchen"),
        initialize: function (models,options) { }
    }), Collection = new MainCollection;
```

Here is a log of Collection and Collection coverted to JSON:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming Collection is your collection's name (that's pretty confusing I have to say), [this](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-toJSON) is what you're looking for:

```
self.$el.prepend(compiled(Collection.toJSON()));
```

**Edit:**
Don't forget you're fetching the data asynchronously. So when you're evaluating your template, the data hasn't come back yet, and your collection's still empty. Listen to the end of the request ('sync' event I think) or some other events so you know when the collection's populated OR use the success option of the fetch method to specify a callback :)

As for your logs. When you log an object, it will be automatically updated until you check the details. So you logged it while it was empty, but checked it after it was populated (a few ms afterwards).

Comment: I have just posted a screenshot with log of the Collection object. Thanks for helping me out, 3rd time this week... :)

Comment: So... you have 1 model in your collection, but the toJSON method returns an empty array?

Comment: @hjuster in fact no ;). I'll make a big guess here. You added your console.log just right after the fetch method, didnt you?

Comment: Tnx, I will try that out now